# What happens if I uninstall the Google Settings app?

Tags: google-play-store, insufficient-memory

My android device frequently runs low on free memory space.

Can I delete the Google Settings app?

I want to install a game but it is not installing what should I do?

Comment: "Google Settings" app is actually a part of "Google Play Services". Uninstalling that may break most apps that rely on it, and it needs root access to do that (unless you meant "uninstall the updates, which is also not recommended)

Comment: I've just added the `insufficient-memory` tag to your question. I strongly recommend you reading [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for better alternatives to your idea. Apart from that, your post is a classical [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154): instead of asking what consequences your alleged solution might have, you'd better described your problem and asked for possible solutions ;) Good look, and I bet that tag-wiki really gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you CAN uninstall that App.  At a minimum, you would need ROOT to do it.

This probably wouldn't have any immediate effects, until you wanted to make any change to your settings (in which case, you wouldn't have the tool to do it).